# Why is it when I override OnRender for a FrameworkElement it is only called once?

Tags: c#, wpf

I override OnRender in a FrameworkElement, but I only see it get called when the FrameworkElement is first created. Shouldn't it be getting called repeatedly? I do not know when Render is supposed to occur, but I would expect at the very least that clearing the visuals in the FrameworkElement's visual collection and drawing a new set of lines would force render to occur again, but the break Point I set in OnRender is not being hit more than once.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
  base.OnRender(drawingContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are accustomed to how the standard on demand painting in Win32
>   or Windows Forms work, you might expect to see this called regularly,
>   whenever the window is resized, or partially obscured and uncovered.
>   in fact, it is called only once !
>
> It turns out that on-demand rendering is not as similar to old style
>   Win32 programming as you might think. WPF will call your OnRender
>   method, whenever it needs to know, what content your visual displays.
>   But the way graphics acceleration works in WPF means that this happens
>   far less often than the equivalent repaints in Win32.
>
> WPF caches the rendering instructions (sometimes referred to as
>   retained mode as compared to immediate mode in Win 32).
>
> the extent and form of this caching are not documented, but caching
>   clearly occurs.

from :

[WPF render only called once](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=558i6t1dKEAC&pg=PA465&lpg=PA465&dq=wpf%20onrender%20only%20called%20once&source=bl&ots=g_wjLEARNT&sig=1PjjgZ3dSKbOoxn0ZSxPavaDUC4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-E26UomnHsj_iAeU7IGgCg&ved=0CHoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=wpf%20onrender%20only%20called%20once&f=false).

Comment: i'm embarrassed not to have found that prior question when searching. i wonder what i searched. anyway thank you

Comment: if you are talking about the link. it is not from a prior question but from a book. maybe thats why